# Listing indexes and constraints

Tags: sql-server, index, primary-key, constraint

I am looking at a SQL Server database for an application I have inherited. I have not looked into SQL Server for approximately 10 years, so please bear with me.

The database table I am looking at has a `bigint NOT NULL` column called `id`, yet, when I check for constraints, I don't see any, and the same holds true for all database tables.

Am I right in assuming that there is no primary key & no indexing (clustered or nonclustered) on these tables?

I ran the following queries and the results appear to confirm my suspicion:

```
//**returns 0**
select count(*) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS;

//**returns no rows**
select * from sys.indexes
where object_id = (select object_id from sys.objects where name = 'NAME-OF-TABLE');

//**returns all tables in database**
SELECT name
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id,'IsIndexed') = 0;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These two queries may help you.  The first will list all of the tables and indexes on those tables in your database.  If the table does not appear in the list is does not have any indexes defined on it.  These queries assume SQL Server version 2005 or newer.

```
SELECT 
    IndexName = QUOTENAME(I.name), 
    TableName =
        QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(T.[schema_id])) + 
        N'.' + QUOTENAME(T.name), 
    IsPrimaryKey = I.is_primary_key
FROM sys.indexes AS I
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS T
    ON I.[object_id] = T.[object_id]
WHERE
    I.type_desc <> N'HEAP'
ORDER BY 
    TableName ASC, 
    IndexName ASC;
```

The second query will report for each table the identity column, if any on each table in your database.

```
SELECT
    TableName =
        QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(T.[schema_id])) + 
        N'.' + QUOTENAME(T.name), 
    IdentityColumn = COALESCE(QUOTENAME(C.name), N'No identity column')
FROM sys.tables AS T
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.columns AS C
    ON T.[object_id] = C.[object_id]
    AND C.is_identity = 1
ORDER BY
    TableName ASC;
```

To limit the queries to a specific table add a `WHERE` clause similar to:

```
WHERE T.name = N'NAME-OF-TABLE'
```

Answer (score 2):

No, something is incorrect.

The check on `sys.indexes` should return a row even if your table has no indexes.  The heap still has a record in `sys.indexes` with a `type_desc` of 'HEAP' and `type` of 0.

I think you probably need to make sure you are in the right database context since `OBJECT_ID()` and `sys.objects` are database-specific.

Try this:

```
USE MyDatabase

SELECT *
FROM sys.indexes
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('schema.MyTableName')
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you're interested in all constraints but INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS doesn't seem to return the DEFAULT constraints -- [TABLE_CONSTRAINTS (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181757.aspx)

> CHECK, UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY

This query will do a simple count against the sys.objects DMV:

```
select COUNT(*)
from sys.objects o
where o.type_desc like '%CONSTRAINT%';
```

If you are interested in listing the tables, you could run something like this:

```
select distinct
   o.object_id
 , QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name) as [object_name]
 , o.type_desc
 , case when dc.parent_object_id is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as has_default_constraint
 , case when cc.parent_object_id is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as has_check_constraint
 , case when fk.parent_object_id is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as has_foreing_key
 , case when kc.parent_object_id is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as has_primary_key
from sys.objects o
inner join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = o.schema_id
left outer join sys.default_constraints dc on dc.parent_object_id = o.object_id and dc.schema_id = o.schema_id
left outer join sys.check_constraints cc on cc.parent_object_id = o.object_id and cc.schema_id = o.schema_id
left outer join sys.foreign_keys fk on fk.parent_object_id = o.object_id and fk.schema_id = o.schema_id
left outer join sys.key_constraints kc on kc.parent_object_id = o.object_id and kc.schema_id = o.schema_id
where o.is_ms_shipped = 0
  and o.type = 'U'
order by [object_name];
```

This one should give you the info on your indexes:

```
select o.name
 , i.*
from sys.objects o
inner join sys.indexes i on i.object_id = o.object_id
where o.is_ms_shipped = 0
  and i.object_id > 100
  and i.index_id > 0
order by o.name
   , i.index_id;
```

- Index_Id = 0 -- HEAP (won't show up)
- Index_Id = 1 -- CLUSTERED
- Index_Id > 1 -- NONCLUSTERED

Comment: could you explain why you have `object_id > 100` ?

Comment: @bluevoodoo1 -- not mandatory but < 100 are the system objects but since using o.is_ms_shipped = 0, should not include them anyway. Just playing safe, that's all